# Vim - if/elseif/else statements in for loop (command mode)

Tags: vim

I'm trying to generate a bunch of text in `vim` (command mode) using for loops, e.g.

```
:for i in range(1,10) | put=i | endfor
```

this outputs `12345678910`

I want to add logic inside of the for loop like the following pseudo code:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | if i>5 put=i endif | endfor
```

My issue is that, after exhausting google searches, I am unable to find the proper syntax for producing this kind of `if` statement. Does anyone know how to perform `if`, `elseif` and/or `else` statements in vim's command mode?

Edit:
so I finally found `vimscript`

so now I have:

```
func! Test()
    for i in range(1,10)
        for j in range(1,10)
            if i<10
                echo i*j
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
endfunction
```

so i can 
    :call Test()

which outputs `12345678910`, but it doesn't insert it into the page..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Every if/elseif/else/endif is a command on its own, so on one line that would be:

```
:for i in range(1,10) | if i > 5 | put =i | endif | endfor
```